# NameError: name 'cost' is not defined – when calling function

Tags: python, function, nameerror

I am a newbie in Python programming and having trouble with this simple program that calculates the Tile Price given 2 dimensions:

> Objective: Calculate the total cost of tile it would take to cover a floor plan of width and height, using a cost entered by the user.

```
print ("NOTE: The unit of cost is in dollars and dimension unit is in feet")

def cost_o_tile(cost, width, height):
    while True:
        cost = int(input("Cost of each tile:"))
        width = int(input("What is the width of the floor?"))
        height = int(input("What is the height of the floor?"))
        try:
            if cost < 0 or width < 0 or height <0:
                print ("\n Please enter non-negative integers")
                break
            else:
                 return ("In order to cover your {} X {} floor, you will need to pay {} dollars".format(width,height,cost*width*height))
        except ValueError: 
            print ("No valid integer! Please try again ...")


cost_o_tile(cost, width, height)
```

I understand that I can declare the variables outside of the function and the code would works. However, I want these variables inside the loop so they can be validated by `except ValueError`.

Comment: Where do you define cost? Why are you passing cost in if that's what you're trying to calculate? When you write `cost_o_tile(cost, width, height)`, you're giving the function data.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: he has a cost per tile (passed as an argument) and a cost for the whole floor (what he is calculating).

Comment: @HughBothwell Ah

Comment: You need to define a variable called cost that holds the per tile cost.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, cost is just the price tag of the Tile. Cost is just a parameter.

Comment: @ThienNghiem You don't have a variable called cost outside the function though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate if I have cost outside the function, this argument can't be validated by "except ValueError". I hope my intention is clear.

Comment: When you write `cost_o_tile(cost, width, height)`, the arguments cost, width and height are the data that you're giving the function to use. If the first parameter "cost" is the price per tile, you need to set what that price is. If you're asking for the data inside the function, there's no point in passing that data in though. Just get rid of the parameters.

Comment: @ Carcigenicate: you are right! I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your function `cost_o_lite` shouldn't take any parameter:

```
def cost_o_tile():
    ...

print(cost_o_tile())
```

And don't forget to print the result.

You can also separate concerns:

First write an algorithm to calculate the total cost:

```
def cost_o_tile(cost, width, height):
    if cost < 0 or width < 0 or height < 0:
        raise ValueError
    return cost * width * height
```

Then write user interface code:

```
print ("NOTE: The unit of cost is in dollars and dimension unit is in feet")

while True:
    try:
        cost = int(input("Cost of each tile:"))
        width = int(input("What is the width of the floor?"))
        height = int(input("What is the height of the floor?"))
        total = cost_o_tile(cost, width, height)
        print("In order to cover your {} X {} floor, you will need to pay {} dollars"
              .format(width, height, total))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("No valid integer! Please try again ...")
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. I shouldn't have passed the arguments in the parameter before defining them.

Answer (score 1):

Making your functions as pure as possible is a key to writing good, maintainable code, and this certainly does not include potentially infinite loops and user input.

There are no variables `cost`, `width`, or `height` in global scope as there should be. This is the cause of your error.

1. The code for input must be moved outside
2. Remove loops
3. You can worry about error handling once you get your code working.

---

**First Pass**

```
def cost_o_tile(cost, width, height):
    return ("In order to cover your {} X {} floor, you will need to pay {} dollars"\
                          .format(width, height, cost * width * height))

cost, width, height = map(int, input("Enter 3 space separated integers: ").split())
print(cost_o_tile(cost, width, height))
```

---

**Second Pass**

Once you have a basic program working, you can look at error handling:

```
def cost_o_tile(cost, width, height):
    try:
        if cost < 0 or width < 0 or height < 0:
            return "Parameters cannot be lesser than 0"
    except ValueError:
        return "Please provide numbers only"

    return ("In order to cover your {} X {} floor, you will need to pay {} dollars"\
                          .format(width, height, cost * width * height))

cost, width, height = map(int, input("Enter 3 space separated integers: ").split())
print(cost_o_tile(cost, width, height))
```

---

**Final Pass**

Now, with error handling in place, you can finally look at loops.

```
def cost_o_tile(cost, width, height):
    try:
        if cost < 0 or width < 0 or height < 0:
            return "Parameters cannot be lesser than 0"
    except ValueError:
        return "Please provide numbers only"

    return ("In order to cover your {} X {} floor, you will need to pay {} dollars"\
                          .format(width, height, cost * width * height))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        cost, width, height = map(int, input("Enter 3 space separated integers: ").split())
        print(cost_o_tile(cost, width, height))

        if input("Continue? ").lower() not in {'y', 'ye', 'yes'}:
            break
```

Comment: The "right answer". I always cringe when I see `input` inside a calculation function. I thought trying to explain purity and side-effects though may detract from the actual problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will try to follow this good programming practice.

Comment: IMO, it is generally not a good practice to turn exception into a result (string value here). I prefer let the exception go down to the caller code (the main function I would say). See my answer.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Not always! Sometimes it is perfectly okay to encapsulate error handling logic within functions. But I agree with you on the fact that in more cases than not, the caller should handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
cost_o_tile(cost, width, height)
```

The problem is with the `cost` argument when you're calling the `cost_o_tile` function in line 18 of your code. If you look closely, it hasn't been defined outside of the function scope, hence the error.